# Intel DP35DP No Boot

Tags: boot, motherboard

**Background and BIOS**

I just bought an Intel DP35DP motherboard. I think it came with the latest BIOS Version (572), but I burned the ISO from Intel anyway. I went to run it in normal mode (BIOS jumper on pins 1 and 2, according to manual), and it gave me a prompt to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to continue with the BIOS update, then went through some loading of files, then it said CD-ROM not detected, even though I was running it from a CD.

I tried in recovery mode (jumper cap removed), and it didn't show anything on the screen. I waited 5-10 minutes like the instructions said, powered it down and back up, and it said it has version 572.

At this point, I'm on normal mode (jumper cap on pins 1 and 2).

**Booting**

However, when I try to boot off a CD, it doesn't get anywhere. Yes, it is first in the boot order, and the same thing happens when I manually choose to boot from the disc. I tried to load Ubuntu 12.04 from it, and it seems like it starts to load the files (the typical white lines on the screen), then it cuts to the purple loading screen and freezes. The activity light on the optical drive. stops flashing at this point. Other times it doesn't even try to load Ubuntu, and it just kind of stops short of booting. I tried putting in a Windows 7 install disc, and it won't boot from it either, although once I got the "Loading files for setup" progress bar, but it never filled, and the activity light is not flashing. I can also tell that the disc is not spinning up like it should.

USB Boot also doesn't work either. I'm trying to boot from a syslinux based flash drive, and it just says boot error. I'm going to try just a Unetbootin Ubuntu flash drive and see if that works, which I doubt; I will update this post with the results.

**EDIT: Well I can get to Unetbootin menu, which is a first. I chose "Try Ubuntu without Installing" and I just have a fast blinking cursor...**

The HDD, as you may have assumed, is empty. When I manually boot from it just to make sure it gives a correct error, it does.

**What else I've done**

I've unplugged and regplugged in the SATA power and data for the hard drive and optical drive. I guess it could be the optical drive itself since the discs don't spin up, but USB should at least work...
Tried AHCI and IDE mode, neither work.

**Specs**

Intel DP35DP Motherboard | Intel Q6600 Core 2 Quad | 4GB Memory | 8800GT Sonic 1GB | 500GB HDD

At this point, I am thoroughly confused. If you've had this board/a similar board/a similar problem/any thoughts at all, please let me know.

Comment: OK so I put it on IDE mode, disabled UEFI (potentially some issues with UEFI and AHCI). Now when I run the BIOS upgrade disc, I press Enter to continue. Then it says press any key to continue (actually start flashing). I press a key, activity light flashes for a bit while it says "IFLASH2 Version 2.4 - build 064" and a blinking cursor. Then the light stops flashing.

Comment: anyone have anything?